# Get directory name from file name

Tags: shell-script, filenames, string

I want to make a directory name by extracting parts of a file name. Here are some examples:

1. `server.log.2016-03-20-14` → `20160320`
2. `server-2016-03-17-13-16-Restart.log` → `20160317`

I'm using HP-UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use awk for it.

1)

```
echo server.log.2016-03-20-14 | awk -F'[.]' '{print $3}' | awk -F'[-]' '{print $1$2$3}'
```

2)

```
echo server-2016-03-17-13-16-Restart.log | awk -F'[-]' '{print $2$3$4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass filename to regex check, with sed:

```
echo server.log.2016-03-20-14 | sed 's/server\.log\.\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1\2\3/g'

echo server-2016-03-17-13-16-Restart.log | sed 's/server-\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-Restart.log/\1\2\3/g'
```

If you need more strict regex, for example months can be described with regex

```
0[0-9]\|1[12]
```

and days are

```
0[1-9]\|[12][0-9]\|3[01]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the shell's string manipulation constructs. This requires a POSIX shell, so if you're running an ancient version of HP-UX you may need to call a POSIX shell such as ksh rather than the Bourne shell.

You didn't fully specify how to parse the date. I'm assuming that the first match of `????-??-??` where each of the `??` are digits is the date you want.

```
p=${0#*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]}
s=${0#"$p"}; p=${0%"$p"}
p=${p#"${p%??????????}"}
year=${p%??????}; p=${p#?????}
month=${p%???}; day=${p#???}
echo "$year$month$day"
```

Not the most readable code but it works.